# Изменение шрифта

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы текст сам по себе уменьшил шрифт, если вышел за рамки дива?

Comment: Можно попробовать SVG: [Как растянуть текст на всю длину страницы?]( http://hashcode.ru/questions/100949/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Узнать длину DIV в пикселях
2. Узнать длину текста в пикселях [ссылка 1](http://forum.woweb.ru/topic39040.html), [ссылка 2](https://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0#hl=ru&newwindow=1&biw=1366&bih=609&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85&oq=javascript+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...23169.27952.0.28408.13.12.1.0.0.0.568.3398.2-2j3j3j1.11.0.V6tMuactsko&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3fa92404c07a4654)
3. Если длина текста больше DIV, то в цикле уменьшать размер шрифта, пока текст не станет помещаться в DIV

Comment: Упс :) Наверно надо было готовый код выложить, а не алгоритм? :) Дайте еще один минус, пожалуйста, хоть значок "Давление коллектива" заработаю :)